# Is there a way in python to filter all dataframes within a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, filter, filtering

I have a dictionary that has excel names as keys and its contents as values. I basically have a dictionary consisting of multiple dataframes.
Now I would like to filter this dictionary (and all the dataframes within it) according to specific characteristics.

E.G.:

```
dictionary = {'contact': 
    ID  companyID   Anrede  Titel   firstname   surname
0   3025    2705    Mrs.    Sam Smith
1   3026    2706    Mr.     Michael Smith
2   3027    2710    Mr.     Christian   Peterson
,
'geography':
    ID  companyID randomID  ContinentID
0   1   3060    0   1.0
1   6   3060    2   1.0
2   7   2710    0   1.0
3   24  7530    0   6.0
4   28  3759    0   6.0
,
...
}
```

sorry I had no clue how to show it properly. I hope you understand the principle.

Now I would like to filter it by the companyID for example, or by the surname even...

Surname is especially weird to me - shouldn't there be a way to connect these dataframes via the companyID for example and then easily filter it by the surname, meaning I only see all the inputs where they have someone working with the name Smith for example.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you have a dictionary of dataframes? Seems a bit strange... couldn't you concatenate the dataframes first then do your filtering?

Comment: so basically before adding them all into one dictionary I just build one big dataframe based on a common ID..?

Comment: That's what I'd do. Could you provide some reproducible test dataframes that we can test on?

Comment: Thank you for the help, @najeem nailed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user32882 pointed out, it's better to merge the multiple dataframes into one based on 'ID' or 'companyID' and then perform the filtering. You can merge them by 'companyID' like below.

```
final_df = None
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    value = value.set_index(['ID', 'companyID'])
    # add an extra level of column where the level is the key from dict
    value.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[key], value.columns])
    if not type(final_df) == pd.DataFrame:
        final_df = value
    else:
        final_df = final_df.merge(value, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

```
Out:
             contact                            geography            
              Anrede Titel  firstname   surname  randomID ContinentID
ID companyID                                                         
0  3025       2705.0  Mrs.        Sam     Smith       NaN         NaN
1  3026       2706.0   Mr.    Michael     Smith       NaN         NaN
   3060          NaN   NaN        NaN       NaN       0.0         1.0
2  3027       2710.0   Mr.  Christian  Peterson       NaN         NaN
6  3060          NaN   NaN        NaN       NaN       2.0         1.0
7  2710          NaN   NaN        NaN       NaN       0.0         1.0
24 7530          NaN   NaN        NaN       NaN       0.0         6.0
28 3759          NaN   NaN        NaN       NaN       0.0         6.0
```

There are few `NaN`s because you dont have matching indices in every dataframe. I hope your actual data is mroe coherent. Once you have this 'merged' dataframe, you can filter over any column you like.

**Explanation**

You have different 'sets' of columns which are represented as separate key value pairs in the dict. I assume that you want to merge these dataframes with 'ID' and 'companyID' as some sort of index. So that's what the above code achieves. It also adds an extra level of column index to denote from which 'key' the set of columns came.

Comment: I didn't know about the MultiIndexing, looks great
I think this will actually help a great deal! Thank you a lot!